# What does the letters 'JHS' mean?

Tags: catholicism, symbolism, word-study

Can you tell me what the letters **JHS** mean? You can see them on the picture below. I am from Slovakia (East Europe) and we speak Slovak and these letters are from Catholic church. I saw these letters on many pantings in Slovak churches. But I do not know their meaning.

Thanks for explanation.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's one of many shorthand names for "Jesus"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christogram

> In the Latin-speaking Christianity of medieval Western Europe (and so among Catholics and many Protestants today), the most common Christogram became "IHS" or "IHC", denoting the first three letters of the Greek name of Jesus, ΙΗΣΟΥΣ, iota-eta-sigma, or ΙΗΣ.
>
> The Greek letter iota is represented by I, and the eta by H, while the Greek letter sigma is either in its lunate form, represented by C, or its final form, represented by S. Because the Latin-alphabet letters I and J were not systematically distinguished until the 17th century, "JHS" and "JHC" are equivalent to "IHS" and "IHC".

Comment: I was under the impression that it was the first two letters and the last one, following Greek convention to mark with the last letter the case the word is in (see **ΙϹ** **ΧϹ** for **Ι**ΗϹΟΥ**Ϲ** **Χ**ΡΙϹΤΟ**Ϲ** and **ΜΡ** **ΘΥ** for **Μ**ΗΤΗ**Ρ** **Θ**ΕΟ**Υ** in Byzantine icons, for example).

Comment: Does this also explain the slang (albeit profane) exclamatory phrase "Jesus H. Christ!" that I heard with some frequency in my youth?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast [Seems like a distinct possibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_H._Christ).

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/25716/192360   @KorvinStarmast  I learned something new today thanks to your comment

Comment: @Kris a pleasure to serve. :)

Comment: You say they used Roman letters for "I" and "S", and then retained the Greek letter that looks like a Roman "H" rather than using the Roman "E"?  Why the inconsistency?

Answer (score 4):

Jesus Hominum Salvator (Latin: Jesus Savior of Mankind) JHS.
this is the direct explanation to your picture. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research into this, and the funny thing is, nobody seems to know for certain. In Hoc Signus is another common explanation. But there doesn’t seem to be a source that answers this question with 100% certainty

Answer (score -3):

JHS represents IHS, which is the hidden surname of Bacchus Dionysus.

JHS/IHS is an acronym of "Isis, Horus, Serapis", the pagan Trinity of Egypt.

Comment: Er.. not very likely is it.. -10 if possible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).